# How can i save today's day to a database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

How can i save today's day to a database with php?

I'm trying with:

```
    $datenow=date('Y-m-d');

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (age,wname,slid,time,sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("isdds", $year, $reasons,$appy_level,$datenow,$sex);
```

this isn't working it writes 0000-00-00 to the database.

Comment: How is your database table looking? Which database you are running? Provide some more infos please

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to make a column in the table with the timestamp as default?

Comment: Also the field that is been used to save the time,

Comment: Does it work when you use $datenow = new DateTime(); ? -- see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your database setup, remove the PHP date and use the mysql built in `NOW()` method. This will require your time field to have a data type of one of DATETIME or similiar.

eg:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (age,wname,slid,time,sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isdds", $year, $reasons, $appy_level, $sex);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 INSERT INTO user (age,wname,slid,time,sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURDATE(), ?)
```